# What exactly is the difference between a frontend and a backend when it comes to websites?

Tags: request, frontend, backend

I'm fairly sure that the simplest explanation is that the frontend is what you can see on the website and the backend is everything that happens behind the scenes.

But I'm trying to make my own web site and I'm not sure how this distinction applies to it.

The web site is not supposed to allow for account creation or anything, its just really supposed to request my Instagram posts and more or less display them. (Its an art gallery of sorts)

I'm confused as to whether the requesting is considered backend or frontend. I'm leaning towards frontend because it causes a visual change but then I'm wondering if that's the case, would a web site like this even need a backend?

Comment: Welcime to Stack Overflow. Please, have a look on [what to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site. Your question is quite broad, which cannot have one definitive answer. I would recommend you to read something like [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/front-end-vs-back-end) to just get your understanding clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have pure front end websites too. For example, websites that have static information can be only front end. And You're right that your website sounds pure front end since you're requesting the Instagram service (which becomes your backend here).

The front end code runs completely on the client browser while the backend code runs on a server/cloud. This is the main distinction.

Why do we need backend code to run on the server? If you can have a website that is pure front end i.e. runs completely on the client side, will it be fast enough? That's where we split the heavy logic and place it on the server to give less work to the client browser. Hence the front end focuses on displaying/rendering the data while the backend focuses on fetching and processing the data.